# How to remove RCP view icon?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the plugin.xml  for each view I have icon text box. to display icon beside the text for the view title.

I want the view title only without the icon.
How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class that extends ViewPart you can override the getTitleImage method:

```
@Override
public Image getTitleImage() {
    return null;
}
```

You should then just get the text in the view title with no icon.

**Edit**
The above code works on Eclipse 4.1.2. For Eclipse 3.7.0 you can use an empty image:

```
@Override
public Image getTitleImage() {
    return new Image(getSite().getShell().getDisplay(), new Rectangle(0, 0,
            1, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick,
I've made what you suggested but I get this error

[[null argument:A part's title image must be non-null]]

Is there something else but null to disable the image ?

Comment: I've verified that the above code works on Eclipse 4.1.2. What version are you using?